# How to convert HTML to PDF in AWS Lambda using Python as a run environment

Tags: python, aws-lambda, html2pdf

Is there any Python Library or Tool from which I can convert HTML to PDF (image, styles) in AWS Lambda.
I searched on google, but failed to get any suitable solution. Mostly looking MIT or BSD licences tool. I checked wkhtmltopdf, but it is LGPLv3 licences.

No third party API(html2pdf).

Answer (score -1):

Use [pdfkit](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/), and then make sure it's included in [the Lambda deployment package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) when you first create your Lambda function.

Comment: No.  pdfkit has system dependencies.